# In Stack Overflow for Teams, how can you find articles that are NOT in any collection?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, articles

You can see a list of all the articles on a Team at `https://stackoverflow.com/c/<your-team>/articles`, and all the articles in a specific collection at `https://stackoverflow.com/c/<your-team>/collections/<collectionID>`.

But how can you find "orphan" articles, that are left outside of any collection? (I mean, without just checking every single article.)